# Printing in Devc

Tags: c

I wrote a simple code with dev but it does not return any thing.but with code block answer shows.what is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x,y,z;
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    while(z!=0){
        z=x%y;
        printf("%d",z);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this fixes your problem?

Comment: i tried but vote up require 15 reputation and i dont have,i'm new to this site,sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It invokes **[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** because `z` is used uninitialized.

```
while( z!= 0)  
       ^
       |
     z is uninitialized
```

You may get any thing either expected or unexpected result. Program may crash also. On different compilers you may get different results, which is the case here.

Comment: Also you can compile with warnings and most compilers will let you know about this. For gcc try -Wall -Wextra -Werror

Answer (score 8):

Two problems I can see:

```
1. Value to z is un-assigned. So garbage.
2. Value of z will not change, so it's infinite loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to see the output because it is closing the terminal / output window as soon as the program exits.

**In code::block, they run a script to hold the output window until you press `enter`.**
you can have same effect by using a `getch()` call at the end, before returning. this will wait for your input and give you a scope to see the result.

Besides, your program has several issues as other answers pointed out. fix them accordingly.

Comment: That's not the case anyway.

Comment: @haccks, the OP asked like `does not return any thing.but with code block answer shows`, so I thought he is concern about not able to see anything as output, but in code::block.

Answer (score 1):

in Your Code you was Assigned z but not initialized  z and you are checking `while(z!=0)` so your code does not return value , fist assigned z to any value for example from `scanf`.